# Do Black Arrow Multistrikes Proc Lock & Load?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I know that Multistrike is the highest priority stat when playing as a Survival hunter. However what I want to know is whether or not multistrikes from Black Arrow can trigger Lock and Load for your explosive shot.

Answer (score 0):

**No it does not.**

I am unable to find the `blue` source for this but once upon a time it did.

In Beta LnL was procced by Multistrike but in Blizzards Eyes it made the Spec to reliant on it so they changed it back again.